# asp.net target framework, and downgrading .net version

Tags: asp.net, web-config, target-framework

I have a subscription to a web hosting provider for website. I am trying to make a simple aspx web page form that receives data and emails it to a specified email. The problem is that the remote server uses the .net version 2.0 and my web page is targeting framework 4.5 and when I changed it in visual studio to build on 2.0 I still receive a server error / in application message, either because the web.config file says targetframework =4.5 is not recognized or authentication tag equal to windows receives an error. I do not have access to IIS manager on remote server so I cannot update application pools. Are there any steps I can take to solve my problem or anyone that has a better knowledge can help me out? Thanks

Comment: If you have only 2-3 pages then it's better to created them again with framework 2.0 because there are so many issue in downgrading.

Comment: I did that and received an error with the authentication mode equal to windows. The parser error message recommended that I set up a virtual directory in IIS but I don't have access to IIS! What do I do?

Comment: please share what actual exception you are getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088824/asp-net-runtime-errors-occuring-in-web-config-file-for-aspx-framework-2-0-websi  see this link for full description of my problem with specific exceptions that are occurring.